# How inefficient is it to call jQuery's $(document).ready() multiple times?

Tags: jquery, performance

Say I have many separate JS files that I link to from my HTML's `<head>` and each of the JS-files start with:

```
$(document).ready(function({
    // some code that does stuff that make me happy
});
```

Regardless of why I'm doing this; is it bad practice perfomance wise?

Comment: What if you measure it before asking? **EVERY** performance-related question should be preceeded with some research and profiling.

Comment: My question is do they all have to run on ready? ;)

Comment: @zerkms I would but I'm on a deadline fixing someone else's mess :-)

Comment: @Reinoud Schuijers: when you're on a deadline - it would be the least thing you should care about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It affects performance very minimally.  if multiple functions are registered, "ready" functions in js frameworks generally just execute them sequentially. Beware of the order if it matters in your code but performance should be fine.

(So the cost is just more function calls -- probably imperceptible unless its thousands+).

Comment: Oh and i guess you may also consider how queries/variables will have to be done redundantly since the functions don't share the same scope, but that's true of any set of js functions. There are ways to "memoize" to avoid redundantly querying for the same variables if you make them global, though.